# How to properly run a Symfony task in the background from an action?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

```
$path=sfConfig::get('sf_app_module_dir')."/module/actions/MultiTheading.php";
foreach($arr as $id)
{
     if($id)
         passthru ("php -q $path $id $pid &");
}
```

when when i running action script is running sequenctly despite "&".

Please help

Comment: What are you trying to do? What's the content of MultiTheading.php?

Comment: Properly running tasks in the background from the action involves creating a daemon and signaling it. It's usually much easier to set up your task to run every x minutes, checking if it has work to do, terminating if not.

Comment: Can you please tell ....how to run scripts in parallel ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two common methods to achieve what you want.

Both involve creating a table in your database (kind of a to-do list). Your frontend saves work to do there.

**The first one** is easier, but it's only ok if you don't mind a slight latency. You start by creating a symfony task. When it wakes up (every 10/30/whatever minutes) it check that table if it has anything to do, simply exists if not. Otherwise it does what it needs to, then marks them as processed.

**The second one** is more work and more error-prone, but can work instantly. You create a task, that daemonizes itself when started (forks, forks again, and sets the parent pid to zero), then goes to sleep. If you have some work to do, you wake it up by sending a signal. Daemonizing and signal sending/receiving can be done with php's pcntl_* functions.